# Rails: Instance variable can be accessed as a local variable in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
posts_controller.rb
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
      def new
        @post = Post.new
      end
    end


_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: post, local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Above is my code.
Why is an instantiation of the class Post as @post in the controller can be accessed as a local variable in the view as post? Hoping I could get an answer from this concern.

Comment: Hey! You've missed an important path in your question: the `new.html.erb` view file. It should have a code construction similar to `render partial: "form", locals: { post: @post }`, which passes the local variable to the underlying view `_form.html.erb`. Take a look at this documentation for the more detailed explanation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#local-variables

Answer (score 1):

The `post` local variable isn't the one defined in the controller action, but the one defined in the view file which renders the partial `_form.html.erb`.

The variable defined in the controller is an instance variable, while the one used in the partial is a local one.

You can see [`ActionController::Renderer#render`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html#method-i-render) for more details.